# Merging two df results in NaN in appended columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am struggling with the following problem for quite a while now and would appreciate any help.

I want to merge df1 & df2 on 'country'.

```
df1.head()
```

```
+---+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|   |  loan_theme_id  | partner_id |               field_partner_name                |         loan_theme_type          |      location_name      |    lat    |    lon     | rural_pct |    city    |     region      |     country     |
+---+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 0 | a1050000000wDrQ |        175 | Koret Israel Economic Development Funds (KIEDF) | Underserved                      | Abu Sanaan, Israel      | 32.958030 | 35.171969  | 0.0       | Abu Sanaan | Israel          | Israel          |
| 1 | a1050000007S5Kt |        485 | Building Markets                                | SME                              | Yangon, Myanmar (Burma) | 16.866069 | 96.195132  | NaN       | Yangon     | Myanmar (Burma) | Myanmar (Burma) |
| 2 | a1050000002YCWe |        369 | AsociaciÍ_n Chajulense de Mujeres (ACMUV)       | Artisan                          | Chajul, Guatemala       | 15.483483 | -91.037070 | NaN       | Chajul     | Guatemala       | Guatemala       |
| 3 | a1050000007qJuI |         77 | Al Majmoua                                      | Vulnerable Populations (Syrian)2 | Aley, Lebanon           | 33.810086 | 35.597326  | 43.0      | Aley       | Lebanon         | Lebanon         |
| 4 | a1050000006FnC9 |        357 | Alivio Capital                                  | Imagen Dental                    | Matamoros,Tamps, Mexico | 25.869029 | -97.502738 | 3.0       | Matamoros  | Tamps           | Mexico          |
+---+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Here are the column types for df1

```
Int64Index: 100 entries, 108 to 549
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------              --------------  -----   
 0   loan_theme_id       100 non-null    category
 1   partner_id          100 non-null    category
 2   field_partner_name  100 non-null    string  
 3   loan_theme_type     100 non-null    category
 4   location_name       100 non-null    string  
 5   lat                 100 non-null    float64 
 6   lon                 100 non-null    float64 
 7   rural_pct           79 non-null     float64 
 8   city                100 non-null    string  
 9   region              100 non-null    string  
 10  country             100 non-null    string  
dtypes: category(3), float64(3), string(5)
memory usage: 19.2 KB
```

```
df2.head()
```

```
+---+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
|   |   country   |      world_region       |   MPI    |
+---+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
| 0 | Afghanistan | South Asia              | 0.309853 |
| 1 | Albania     | Europe and Central Asia | NaN      |
| 2 | Algeria     | Arab States             | NaN      |
| 3 | Armenia     | Europe and Central Asia | NaN      |
| 4 | Azerbaijan  | Europe and Central Asia | NaN      |
+---+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

Column types:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 102 entries, 0 to 101
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   country       102 non-null    string 
 1   world_region  102 non-null    object 
 2   MPI           78 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1), string(1)
memory usage: 3.2+ KB
```

Ensuring that the there is at least some overlap:

```
display(df2[(df2.country == 'Guatemala')])
```

```
+----+-----------+-----------------------------+----------+
|    |  country  |        world_region         |   MPI    |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------+----------+
| 34 | Guatemala | Latin America and Caribbean | 0.113957 |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------+----------+
```

The merge:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='country', how='left')
df3.head()
```

```
+---+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+
|   |  loan_theme_id  | partner_id |               field_partner_name                |         loan_theme_type          |      location_name      |    lat    |    lon     | rural_pct |    city    |     region      |     country     | world_region | MPI |
+---+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+
| 0 | a1050000000wDrQ |        175 | Koret Israel Economic Development Funds (KIEDF) | Underserved                      | Abu Sanaan, Israel      | 32.958030 | 35.171969  | 0.0       | Abu Sanaan | Israel          | Israel          | NaN          | NaN |
| 1 | a1050000007S5Kt |        485 | Building Markets                                | SME                              | Yangon, Myanmar (Burma) | 16.866069 | 96.195132  | NaN       | Yangon     | Myanmar (Burma) | Myanmar (Burma) | NaN          | NaN |
| 2 | a1050000002YCWe |        369 | AsociaciÍ_n Chajulense de Mujeres (ACMUV)       | Artisan                          | Chajul, Guatemala       | 15.483483 | -91.037070 | NaN       | Chajul     | Guatemala       | Guatemala       | NaN          | NaN |
| 3 | a1050000007qJuI |         77 | Al Majmoua                                      | Vulnerable Populations (Syrian)2 | Aley, Lebanon           | 33.810086 | 35.597326  | 43.0      | Aley       | Lebanon         | Lebanon         | NaN          | NaN |
| 4 | a1050000006FnC9 |        357 | Alivio Capital                                  | Imagen Dental                    | Matamoros,Tamps, Mexico | 25.869029 | -97.502738 | 3.0       | Matamoros  | Tamps           | Mexico          | NaN          | NaN |
+---+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+
```

The column types

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 13 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------              --------------  -----   
 0   loan_theme_id       100 non-null    category
 1   partner_id          100 non-null    category
 2   field_partner_name  100 non-null    string  
 3   loan_theme_type     100 non-null    category
 4   location_name       100 non-null    string  
 5   lat                 100 non-null    float64 
 6   lon                 100 non-null    float64 
 7   rural_pct           79 non-null     float64 
 8   city                100 non-null    string  
 9   region              100 non-null    string  
 10  country             100 non-null    string  
 11  world_region        0 non-null      object  
 12  MPI                 0 non-null      float64
```

I really don't get why the result is NaN in in world_region and MPI. I made sure there are no NaNs in df1 & df2 in country and that there is at least some sort of overlap. Also the column types match.

Edit:
Thanks to Paul I tried to retrieve the information about e.g. 'Guatemala' in df1. We can see in the table above that it is actually present in df1. However, running `display(df2[(df2.country == 'Guatemala')])`, returns a empty dataframe. So I tried to run display(df2[(df2.country == ' Guatemala')]), with a extra space at the beginning and now we get some results:

```
+---+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   |  loan_theme_id  | partner_id |            field_partner_name             | loan_theme_type |   location_name   |    lat    |    lon    | rural_pct |  city  |  region   |  country  |
+---+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 2 | a1050000002YCWe |        369 | AsociaciÍ_n Chajulense de Mujeres (ACMUV) | Artisan         | Chajul, Guatemala | 15.483483 | -91.03707 | NaN       | Chajul | Guatemala | Guatemala |
+---+-----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Which leads to the question if there is a function in pandas to check for white spaces in a df column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing a left join specified by `left` keyword in the merge command. This means that if the right dataframe does not have the country that a row in the left one has you'll get NaNs.
For more info on join types and left joins in particular see for example here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

**EDIT:**
This because in one of the dataframes there is an extra blank space around the string. Before joining you can remove the white spaces with the `trim()` function.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for your answer. But df2 has 'Guatemala' as df1 has 'Guatemala' as well in row 3. Shouldn't the join work at least in this case? Thanks again for your time and fast answer!

Comment: You're right. In that case it should work. Are you sure there is no extra space in df1 `Guatemala ` or any other typo? Does `display(df1[(df1.country == 'Guatemala')])` return a row?

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you! You brought up the right idea. Do you know a function with which I could check this in a better way in the future?

Comment: maybe you can remove leading and tailing blank spaces by using the `trim` function and maybe also user `.lower()` in order to have everything lower case and not worry about capitalization any more. However, this does not help versus other typos

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks I'll try it out. If you want, post another suggestion about the blank extra space so I can mark it as the correct answer.